# I can't install dlux and l2switch features in opendaylight

Tags: opendaylight

I am trying to install the `opendaylight` lethium project in my PC. I could start it but, when I try to install the `dlux` feature and `l2switch`, I get this error:

> feature:install odl-dlux-core Error executing command: No matching
>   features for odl-dlux-core/0

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

dlux and l2switch were removed in later versions of opendaylight, but since
you are using lithium, it should work.

do you see the features when you list them with:

```
feature:list
```

where did you download opendaylight from?

Answer (score 0):

Please check which version of ODL in your environment. Because in some new versions, `dlux` became a separate project at https://github.com/opendaylight/dlux. And `l2switch` is also removed from `Controller`.