# Does Opendaylight still have a UI

Tags: sdn, opendaylight

I try to get the web interface of OpenDaylight controller (Magnesium Version).

But I cannot install the features `odl-restconf odl-l2switch-switch odl-mdsal-apidocs odl-dlux-all`

A web interface is still available in ODL controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59878007/i-cant-install-dlux-and-l2switch-features-in-opendaylight) comes up periodically. the DLUX GUI project as well as
the spanning-tree l2switch project are no longer maintained or part of
an OpenDaylight release. You can try an older version of OpenDaylight. Or,
if you are the developer type, you can try to bring DLUX and/or l2switch
up to speed with the current ODL project and possibly get it to build and
install.