# How to start dlux in OpenDaylight Sodium controller

Tags: opendaylight

I know that DLUX is now an independent project, and already separated from ODL's Controller project. However, what should I do if I want to install dlux-* apps in Controller's console? There is no "distribution" directory under DLUX project.

Answer (score 0):

DLUX was removed from the features of ODL in newer version.

You can try to install it from the github repo: https://github.com/opendaylight/dlux or install an older version of ODL.

Here's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60967340/does-opendaylight-still-have-a-ui) about the UI.